# Aliasing different WINDOW clauses in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to have aliases for multiple `Windows` in the same query ?

For e.g. -

```
select 
   cust_id,
   eff_dt,
   row_number() over w AS rec1
from cust
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY eff_dt desc);
```

The above runs **fine**. But it fails when I try to add another `Window` alias:

```
select 
   cust_id,
   eff_dt,
   row_number() over w AS rec1,
   rank() over w2 AS rec2
from cust
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY eff_dt desc),
WINDOW w2 AS (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY version asc);
```

Can anyone please help on how to use both the `Window` aliases above ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with nested query,

```
select
    cust_id,
    eff_dt,
    rec1,
    rank() over w2 AS rec2
from (
    select
    cust_id,
    eff_dt,
    version,
    row_number() over w AS rec1
    from cust
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY eff_dt desc))
WINDOW w2 AS (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY version asc);
```